# Eclipse make each thread print to separate console

Tags: eclipse, multithreading, console, output

Is it possible to set up eclipse so that each thread prints to a seperate console? It is very annoying when the outputs are all garbled together.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if you can really do that , but you will add a name of each thread something like thread.Name = "1" and when you print the information add the name of the thread at the end.

Comment: Yeah, I know you can do that, but it wouldnt help in this case,

Comment: well in console i´ve never do that but whit UI , its more simple. Can you use UI? or just a console